# Using switch_to within .kv from Popup using factory to open another tab within the .kv! I could not achieve it

Tags: python, tabs, kivy, factory

**My 1st aim** is to **open tab** with **id:delft** by using Factory function from .kv file on button click from the Popup section.(**button id: buttontx**) When I click the button, ***I receive this error:***   on_press: Factory.MyLayout().switch_to(MyLayout.ids.delft) NameError: name 'MyLayout' is not defined.

My second aim is to create database from popup .kv and display the name in the tab. Yet I could not start it because I am searching for a solution to my primary problem. Down below you may see my .py and .kv codes.

.PY

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
import time
import smtplib
import psycopg2

Builder.load_file('tabs.kv')


def sendmail():
    username = 'kASASD'
    subject = "SAAT 11"
    password = 'ddsa'
    body = 'DENEME'
    msg = "\r\n".join([
        "From: " + username,
        "To: " + username,
        "Subject: " + subject,
        "",
        body
    ])
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username, password)
    print('sending')
    server.sendmail(username, username, msg.encode("utf-8", errors="ignore"))
    server.quit()
    print('sent')


class MyLayout(TabbedPanel):
    def updates(self, *args):
        # saat, dakika saniye
        self.ids.saat.text = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        # gün ay yıl gün
        self.ids.tarih.text = time.strftime("%d %B %Y %A")
        # 23de mail at
        if time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") == "23:03:00":
            sendmail()



class AwesomeApp(App):

    def build(self):
        t = MyLayout()
        Clock.schedule_interval(t.updates, 1)
        return t



if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

---

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<MyPopup@Popup>
    # pop up kendine sadece 1 tane widget alır. Birkaç şey koymak istiyorsan. Boxlayout falan yapıp içine
    #atman gerekiyor.
    # kutu dışına dokununca kaybolsun mu? - hayır
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint: .4, .4
    #top .9 = yukarının %90'nında dursun diye. x: saga sola
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "top": .8}
    title: "Herhangi bir veri yok. Veri girin"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        Label:
            text: "Herhangi bir veri yok. Veri girin"
            text: "Meta girin"
            size_hint: 1, .2

        TextInput:
            id: table_input
            text: "Metanız"
            size_hint: 1, .2
            font_size: 20
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size: root.width, root.height
            size_hint: 1, .2

            Button:
                text: "Oluştur"
                font_size: 20
                id: create_db

            Button:
                id: buttontx
                text: "Vazgeç"
                font_size: 20
                on_press: Factory.MyLayout().switch_to(MyLayout.ids.delft)

<MyLayout@TabbedPanel>
    do_default_tab: True
    default_tab: delft
    #orantısal küçültür
    size_hint: .99, .99
    #ekranın ortasına bütün kareyi koyar
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    # tabları ortalar - bottom tabları alta atar left_top, left_mid, left_bottom, top_left, top_mid, top_right,
    #right_top, right_mid, right_bottom, bottom_left, bottom_mid, bottom_right
    tab_pos: 'top_mid'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        id: delft
        text: "Anasayfa"

        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                id: saat
                text: "Press the Button =>"
            Label:
                id: tarih
                text: "Press the Button =>"

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "Metalar"
        on_release:
            if inner_meta.text == "Empty" : Factory.MyPopup().open()

        TabbedPanel:
            do_default_tab: False
            #orantısal küçültür
            size_hint: .99, .99
            #ekranın ortasına bütün kareyi koyar
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            # tabları ortalar - bottom tabları alta atar left_top, left_mid, left_bottom, top_left, top_mid, top_right,
            #right_top, right_mid, right_bottom, bottom_left, bottom_mid, bottom_right
            tab_pos: 'left_mid'

            TabbedPanelItem:
                id: inner_meta
                text:"Empty"



    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "Tab 3"

        Image:
            source: "/charac.png"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any need to use `Factory` to open a tab. Just change:

```
            on_press: Factory.MyLayout().switch_to(MyLayout.ids.delft)
```

to:

```
            on_press: app.root.switch_to(app.root.ids.delft)
```

The code `Factory.MyLayout()` was creating a new instance of `MyLayout` (not the one that is created in your `build()` method). And this new instance is not part of your GUI. The code `MyLayout.ids.delft` causes an error because kivy is attempting to evaluate `MyLayout` as a variable, typically containing a reference to an instance of some widget. Even if kivy recognized `MyLayout` as a class, it would not contain the `ids` defined in the `kv` file, since that only appears in the instance of `MyLayout`. The fix uses `app.root` to access the instance of `MyLayout` that is the root widget of your `App`.

Comment: This was the message I received after I clicked up: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.". Thank you for your help and explanation. I wish you a good day.

Comment: You can click the check-mark to indicate the accepted answer.

Comment: I did thanks for letting me know. I appreciate it.